# <Pinescript> How to find previous closures on a condition

Tags: pine-script

Assuming to have a condition "cond". I'm using this code to find a specific bar close before that condition:

```
//@version=4    
a = iff(cond, close[10], na)
    plotshape(a, "a", shape.triangleup  , location.belowbar, color.lime, size=size.normal)
```

When I plot "a", I see it at the exact moment the condition occours and any value I enter in the [] brackets, it doesn't change.
How can I find the close of the tenth bar before my condition?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your full code? Or a minimal reproducible example that compiles?

Comment: Shared now, it is my own answer

Comment: Please edit your question and share your code there.